# TabIndex vs. KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, focus, tabindex, keyboard-navigation

What is the difference between `TabIndex` and `KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex` in WPF? When to use each?

Answer (score 14):

*@akjoshi included a very important piece of information about TabIndex in his answer but I thought a little more explanation would help.*

If you have an `ItemsControl` repeating an item you will end up with a [tab order like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116802/wpf-tabstop-tabindex-in-itemscontrol/12451830#12451830) if you're not careful.

[image]

The solution is simple :

Apply this attached property to the main container of each repeated item.

```
KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
```

This [enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116802/wpf-tabstop-tabindex-in-itemscontrol/12451830#12451830) has all kinds of values, but this is the one to use for nested controls.

Note I've set `IsTabStop=false` for the `ItemsControl` itself (and no this isn't the actualy code for the graphic above).

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentItem.CustomsItems}" IsTabStop="False">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ctl:CustomsItem KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" Margin="0,0,0,8"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 13):

Some controls like `CheckBox` have `TabIndex` property but not all controls have this property, but you may want them to have focus and participate in focus navigation, attached property `KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex` can be used on in such cases. An example of such control is [`Hyperlink`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpf/thread/E34E67FB-392D-4E00-99E6-53B10B700315)

Apart from this [KeyboardNavigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.aspx) class provides a lot other functionality to set focus navigation, like tab navigation behavior, KeyboardNavigationMode etc.

> The navigation behavior of a
>   navigation container can be changed by
>   setting the attached
>   KeyboardNavigation properties
>   TabNavigation, ControlTabNavigation,
>   and DirectionalNavigation. These
>   properties are of type
>   KeyboardNavigationMode and the
>   possible values are Continue, Local,
>   Contained, Cycle, Once, and None. The
>   default value is Continue, which means
>   the element is not a navigation
>   container.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx#Keyboard_Navigation